# Can't create scheduled task in WSO2 DSS 3.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm trying to create a scheduled task in DSS 3.5.0 but the UI seems broken. After choosing "Data service name" a list of operations loads and on this list only one operation shows up and after that, a bunch of... license agreements?

Does anybody know any workaround? Maybe there is a way to create such task in eclipse project or to edit it via xml?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I wanted to choose an operation with an input parameter when schedule only handles non-parameter operations :)